# Revision History in CKAN

Tags: ckan, revisions

Does CKAN provide revision history for datasets?

I see a table and an API call, but I don't see anything in the UI and/or the database when making a modification to a dataset or the metadata fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit a dataset's title and you'll see a row with the new value added to package_revision table.

However 'revisions' is a deprecated feature in CKAN since a few years ago. Along with the patchy REST API, there is a 'history' page for datasets for the purpose of an admin to audit changes.

Activity Stream is the intended replacement, to allow you to see old versions of datasets, and eventually other objects too. Effort is ongoing: https://github.com/ckan/ckan/pull/3972

Comment: If you don't mind, it's more helpful to future readers if you create a new question.