# Called CKAN package_update - lost all resources?

Tags: python, ckan

I am running a CKAN installation. I wanted to update a package's name and some other metadata, but not touch its resources. Later I found out that this can be accomplished using `package_patch` - but before I did, I accidentally called `package_update`. Now all resources in the package seem to be lost... Any way to recover them / roll back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CKAN has no built-in way to recover that data. There is the "activity stream" and its deprecated predecessor "revisions" (see [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48184502/857390)), but AFAIK they cannot be used to restore your dataset.

If you don't have a backup of your data then it is lost.

For the future: an easy way to backup your CKAN data is using the [ckanapi](https://github.com/ckan/ckanapi) command line tool.